# How to plot such a graph with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe:

```
  date       date2      col1   col2
 
2011-05-01  2011-05-01    3     25
            2011-05-02    1     17
            2011-05-03    2     12

2012-05-01  2012-05-01    5     45
            2012-05-02    5     73
```

How can I plot each column (col1 and col2) grouping dataframe by level 0 (date)?

I want to get a graph like this one in the picture.
So date is determined by color, date2 is on x-axis and col1 or col2 are the cols I what to plot separately.

I tried stackplot, but it didn't work, as I can't set the x length:

```
plt.stackplot(df.date2,df.groupby(level=0)['col1'].sum())
```

Picture I want to receive:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Try this:  `df.unstack('date2')['col1'].plot.area()`.. not enough data to duplicate your plot.

Comment: Thank you. It works.

Comment: @user12628549 Please consider accepting  and upvoting the answer if works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using dataframe reshaping:

```
df.unstack('date2')['col1'].plot.area()
```

As @QuangHoang states, this is less costly, you are manipulating fewer columns, this is better:

```
df['col1'].unstack('date2').plot.area()
```

Comment: Upvoted. `df['col1'].unstack('date2').plot.area()` is a little less costly.

Comment: Thanks, @QuangHoang.  Be safe and stay healthy.